# Evenly distribute text objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a built in function in Illustrator to evenly distribute text objects? I edited text in an existing PDF file, but now the text is not aligned properly.

Example:

[image]

I don't know if it is matter, but If I select text object there is a space around object:

[image]

Comment: One thing I found to work: create outline from text, then Align - Vertical Distribute Space. Disadvantage of this method, that I can^t edit text anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that your original document appears to be rotated.  If you deskew everything, then your text should automatically line up correctly.

However, if you need to keep the document at its current angle, you can split each of the text groupings into individual layers, and then line up each of the text blocks.

I would first place guidelines to show where the baseline of each text line should be.  Then, open the Layers panel, and duplicate the layer that contains the text so that you have a layer for each individual line of text. Delete the text inside of each layer so that each one only includes the text that is included on that line.  Then, using the guidelines, move each individual layer into its appropriate vertical location.

Once you have each line in place vertically, make sure one of the layers is located where you would like it horizontally. Whichever layer you select first will be used as the alignment point, so make sure to select the layer in the correct horizontal position first. Start with that layer selected, select all of the other text layers that you want to align, and use the alignment controls at the top of the screen to align them.
[image]